# How can "2p" be a date in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access VBA, `IsDate("2p")` returns `True`.
Can someone explain the logic behind this surprising answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2pm.

Dates are date time things. Whole numbers days since some day in the past. Decimals the time of day as a proportion of 1 day (.5 is 12pm)